# want to Update data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api

I am done with the API coding and whenever I click the update button it doesn't work and doesn't call the API. When I click I want the Update button to call the API and display the data which is called by id in the respective fields so that I can re edit the stored data. I do not know where to do what please help me.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Read() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/emp`)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setAPIData(response.data);
            })
    }, []);

    const setData = (data) => {
        let { Employee_name, Employee_id, Employee_address, Employee_post } = data;
        localStorage.setItem('Employee Name', Employee_name);
        localStorage.setItem('Employee ID', Employee_id);
        localStorage.setItem('Employee Address', Employee_address);
        localStorage.setItem('Employee Position', Employee_post)
    }

    // const updateData = (Employee_id) => {
    //     axios.get(`https://localhost:5000/emp/:Employee_id`)
    //     .then((data) =>{
    //         console.log(data)
    //         setAPIData(update.data);
    //     })
    // } 

    const getData = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/emp`)
            .then((getData) => {
                setAPIData(getData.data);
            })
    }

    const onDelete = (Employee_id) => {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/emp/:Employee_id`)
        .then(() => {
            getData();
        })
    }

    const Data = () => {
            navigate('/')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Table singleLine>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Employee position</Table.HeaderCell>
                        
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Delete</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body>
                    {APIData.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <Table.Row>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_id}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_address}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{data.Employee_post}</Table.Cell>
                                <Link to='/update'>
                                    <Table.Cell> 
                                        <Button onClick={() => setData(data)}>Update</Button>
                                    </Table.Cell>
                                </Link>
                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button onClick={() => onDelete(data.Employee_id)}>Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>
                            </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })}
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
            <Button onClick={Data} type='submit'>Home</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You have a button wrapped in a link, do you intend to do multiple things when clicking there?

Comment: Of course the API is not called when you click the Update button, since the onClick of the button is wired to the setData function that just set data in localStorage

Comment: yes you are right hellogoodnight

Comment: please help me out

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you have a `Link` wrapped around a button which you should remove.

```js
// <Link to="/update">
<Table.Cell>
  <Button onClick={() => setData(data)}>Update</Button>
</Table.Cell>
// </Link>
```

In the `getData` function I recommend to change the name of the variable receiving the data to `response` to not get confused with the function name itself, like you do in the `useEffect`

```js
const getData = () => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/emp`).then((response) => {
    setAPIData(response.data);
  });
};
```

In the `onDelete` function you are not correctly passing the `Employee_id` to the url, you should use `${}`. The same in the commented `updateData` function

```js
const onDelete = (Employee_id) => {
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/emp/${Employee_id}`).then(() => {
    getData();
  });
};
```